# Nodejs + Twitter Streaming API not working tracking certain words

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I was trying to use Nodejs to capture tweets with certain words. Using twitter module, I wrote:

```
var util = require('util'),
  twitter = require('twitter');
var twit = new twitter({
  consumer_key: '***',
  consumer_secret: '***',
  access_token_key: '***',
  access_token_secret: '***'
});

console.log('Bot ON!'); 

twit.stream('statuses/filter', {'track': ['love']}, function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(util.inspect(data));
  });
  stream.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err.message);
  });
});
```

When I execute that code, I can track the word 'love'.
But, if I change for something like 'hyjhuolup', the streaming not show any tweet. I put that word 'hyjhuolup' in the code, tweet in my account (different than account using by the node) and nothing happens. I really don't know why. I have the same problem in other libraries like 'twit'. Anyone know what can I do? Thanks.

**Edit 1:**
I already try this: [Cannot retrieve tweets based on hashtag with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043736/cannot-retrieve-tweets-based-on-hashtag-with-nodejs) but no success.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same problem when I use more than one search term. As long as I use fine, I can retrieve tweets.